# Android Studio Signed APK Build Failure: com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Project was untouched for about a month, made one small JS change and I am getting this error when trying to build.

Execution failed for task ':app:bundleProductionreleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

React Native v0.63.3
Android Studio 4.1.1
Gradle version 6.5
Android Gradle plugin version 4.1.1

Comment: Please don't add "Fixed" to questions - you can add the content as an answer or comment.

Comment: An earlier edit to the question noted that the issue was "[f]ixed by downgrading from android gradle plugin v4.1.1 to v4.0.1"